# how to print the sum of random numbers? c#

Tags: c#

```
        int random = 0;

        int lineNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lineNumber++;

            Random rand = new Random();

            random = rand.Next(1, 1001);

            Console.WriteLine($"Number {lineNumber}:  {random}");
        }
```

I want to print all the random numbers (already done) and then sum all these numbers and print the summary.

Comment: Move `Random rand = new Random();` before the `for`.

Comment: so then what exactly is your problem? "adding numbers" should be one of the most basic and easy things to do IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You create a new Random object every iteration which prevents you from generating a random result, it will always be the same. To sum up the values I made a variable to which you will add a random value every iteration.

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = 0;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            lineNumber++;
            random = rand.Next(1, 1001); // Random number between 1 and 1000
            sum += random; // Sum random values
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0}: {1}", lineNumber, random); // Debug
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of number values: " + sum);
    }
}

// Number 1: 539
// Number 2: 325
// Number 3: 606
// Number 4: 919
// Number 5: 877
// Sum of number values: 3266
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a Linq alternative to to answers:

```cs
Random rand = new Random();
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                              .Select(i => rand.Next(1, 1001));

var sumOfRandomNumbers = randomNumbers.Sum();
            
var linesToPrint = randomNumbers.Select((number, index) => $"Number {index}:  {number}");

foreach (var line in linesToPrint)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.WriteLine(sumOfRandomNumbers);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not only can you move the `Random` initialization outside the for-loop, you can also remove your `linenumber` count since this is already encapsulated in the iterable you use in your for-loop: `i`.

I hereby suggest a solution that also takes advantage of the fact that you can increase a variable with another variable that gets its value assigned at the same time.

```cs
int numberCount = 5;
int sum = 0;
int random;

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++)
{
    sum += random = rand.Next(1, 1001);
    Console.WriteLine($"Number {i+1}: {random}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
```